# How can I show hidden files (starting with period) in NERDTree?

Tags: windows, vim, nerdtree

How can I make [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) show files that begin with an `.` (period)?

I have a file named `.hgignore` in a project directory. If I browse to that directory using NERDTree, the file is not displayed within the tree.

I am using gvim on Windows.

Answer (score 490, accepted):

Press <kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) to toggle hidden files in the NERDTree explorer window.

To enable this behavior by default, add this line to your `.vimrc` file:

```
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
```

For more detail, access the NERDTree help file `:help NERD_tree.txt` and search for "hidden".

Comment: And to hide hidden files by default, put `let NERDTreeShowHidden=0` into your vimrc.

Comment: if you are in a Lua file: `vim.g.NERDTreeShowHidden=1`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Neovim on Linux, the configs are in the file :

home/[user]/.config/nvim/init.vim

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. ;)