# Vim - NERDTree - how to open a hidden folder (.name) in NERDTree plugin?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have a hidden folder which name starts with . (dot)
I am editing files withing the parent folder but want to be able to access files within the hidden one as well from within NERDTree plugin under vim.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show hidden files (starting with period) in NERDTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057359/how-can-i-show-hidden-files-starting-with-period-in-nerdtree)

Comment: The question is exactly like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057359) and I leave a downvote and also vote to close.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, the NERDTree shows also hidden files.

This could be found in the docs of NERDTree that appear if you hit <kbd>?</kbd> in the NERDTree window or type `:he NERDTree` (specific: `:he NERDTreeMappings)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Answer (score 14):

To shows hidden files/folders by default, add this line to your .vimrc file:

```
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
```

Hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to toggle between show and hide hidden files/folders.

If you ignore file/folder(like .git/ , .DS_Store/ etc) in NerdTree, add this line to your vim script:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.DS_Store$', '\.git$'] " ignore files in nerd tree
```